# Regarding passing strings to win32 api functions

Tags: c++, winapi

I was wondering if there is any advantage (for shorter strings only) of using a `string` datatype instead of a char array, or simply the string such as:

```
TextOut(hDC, 10, 10, "Hello", sizeof("HEllO") - 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, this doesn't matter at all.

That said, the Win32 APIs require `LPSTR`s or `LPWSTR`s, so anything which is not "one of those" will first have to be converted into the appropriate `char*` type, so a very tiny bit of extra work is required.

I'd say the vastly bigger consideration is using a datatype which is convenient/familiar/easy for you to work with.

Answer (score 1):

One difference between a string datatype and the inline string as you've used them above is that using a separate named reference (whether the type is a string or char array) prevents the common bug where you change the string but forget to change the copy inside the sizeof().  If the new string is a different length, it will have undesired consequences.  Having a single place that allows you to update both simultaneously, whether via a const char* or string datatype, is a better practice.

```
const TCHAR TEXTOUT_TEXT[] = _T("Hello");
TextOut( hDC, 10, 10, TEXTOUT_TEXT, sizeof(TEXTOUT_TEXT) / sizeof(TEXTOUT_TEXT[0]) - 1 );
```

Comment: @user9955048
Thanks man, but I was just asking about the difference between the three. Since I do a lot of assembly programming, I am most comfortable with using pointers for strings. So most of the times, I use something like:
'char *text="hello";'
But thanks for pointing that out!